# Unsupported signal error connecting Raspberry PI to a HDMI port at Sony Bravia

Tags: raspberry-pi, sony, hdmi

I bought a Raspberry PI and connected to one of my Sony Bravia's HDMI port. I got `unsupported signal, check your device output` error. I have another TV, another model of Sony Bravia, that TV can display Raspberry PI's output. My first TV support video signals of 1080i, 720p, 1080p and display resolution is 1366 x 768. I looked for the similar problems and some people complain HDMI cable problem. But not sure, it is cable problem. I think it is setting problem. Is there any setting in Raspberry PI for HDMI output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it with another hdmi cable ! The new cable was quite a bit shorter but worked fine .

Comment: Any HDMI cable type? I am worried I bought a new one and still have the same problem.

Comment: I believe it is specificated as a hdmi 1.4 cable. Nothing special , under 2 euro in price

Comment: Sure, I'll search tomorrow and replace the existing one. Will update. Thanks.

Comment: Yes you are right. I changed the cable and it works. But don't know why in some cases still go back to the unsupported signal problem. If there is a display text of 720p on the screen, it works. Sometimes that text doesn't appear and unsupported signal comes back.

Comment: I found the solution here (http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21445). Now I force the HDMI output to be 720p by setting hdmi_mode=4. Then it works all the time now.